# PHP Regular expression percent or currency

Tags: php, regex

I would need to be able to extract the following in PHP, and it's driving me crazy.

Take for example the following string:

`$text = "Nalgene Narrow-Mouth Loop-Top 16-oz. Water Bottle for $4 + pickup and %40 off at REI";`

On the one hand, I'd need to be able to extract:

`$4 as extracted currency`

and

`%40 as extracted percentage`

And differentiate which one is the currency and which on is the percentage.

To make it a bit more complicated, I should also grab it if the currency would'be been:

`$4.11 or $ 4.10 (not the spacing and the comma)`

or if the percentage would've been:

`% 40 (note the spacing)`

I'm really stuck, thanks..

Comment: Where on earth is the percent sign written before the number?

Comment: You're right ;) but it happens... messy feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "Nalgene Narrow-Mouth Loop-Top 16-oz. Water Bottle for $4.3 + pickup and % 40 off at REI";
preg_match('/%([ 0-9]+?) /', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
preg_match('/\$([ .0-9]+?) /', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: This is already great! Thank you. But it doesn't pick up, for example:   
$text = "Nalgene Narrow-Mouth Loop-Top 16-oz. Water Bottle for $4.13"; if the $4.13 is at the end of the line. I tried to remove the space before the trailing /. It then does find the currency, but only the $4, so it loses everything behind the comma...

Comment: @KoenKonings, try `/%([0-9.]+)/`

Comment: @KoenKonings, use this instead /%([ 0-9]*)/ just trim data after fetching